# Python, could I import * without Imported classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

Let's pretend that I have this file called `file1.py`:

```
from app1 import ClassX

class Class1:
    pass

class Class2:
    pass
```

If in another file called `file2.py` I want to import `Class1` and `Class2` without explicit import this classes I usually need to use

```
from file1 import *
```

My problem is, when I do it I'm importing the `ClassX` too, but I don't want to import the `ClassX` and I don't to import Class1 and Class2 explicit.

There is some way to import only the classes that I really developed in `File1`?

Comment: This is what [`__all__`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python) is for. It controls what is automatically included when you `from foo import *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put a finer point on Jonathon Reinhart's comment on the question:

```
# app2.py
from app1 import ClassX

__all__ = ['Class1', 'Class2']

class Class1:
    pass

class Class2:
    pass
```

```
# test.py
from app2 import *

c = Class1()
d = Class2()
try:
    e = ClassX()
except NameError:
    print "Working as intended!"
```

Comment: Adam, this is cool. But I can see just one problem, if I create an Class3 on file1.py, I need to add to __all__ var. There is another way to do this? Whitout need of add to __all__ every time I create a new class?

Comment: @Rubico there's no way (that I'm aware of) to create a so-called "blacklist" of items to be imported. You should really try to avoid the `from modulename import *` construction, anyway.